# Infinite product of trigonometric function

Tags: infinite-product, weierstrass-factorization

I would like to find the infinite product of $\frac {\sin x\pi}{\sin \sqrt{x}\pi}$. I have tried to seperate them into two parts namely $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2-x^2}{n^2-x}$$ but it seems to not fit the o.g. question. How can I do this?
Tips are accepted.

Comment: $x$ can't be an integer, or the value is $0,$ at least for terms $x$ not a perfect square. But if not, it is unclear what the infinite product is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$\frac{\sin (\pi  x)}{\pi  x}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty  \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\sin \left(\pi  \sqrt{x}\right)}{\pi  \sqrt{x}}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty  \left(1-\frac{x}{n^2}\right)$$ Making the ratios
$$\frac{\sin (\pi  x)}{\sin \left(\pi  \sqrt{x}\right)}=\sqrt{x}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2-x^2}{n^2-x}$$